# Better and prettier syntax for a part of a code

Tags: javascript

I don't want to disturb but I really don't know how to do it. This is not a real functional problem in itself. The app can work like this, but it's more of a clarity issue. I have a script using vis-network (you don't have to know it, it won't be there). Before using the library, I'm running some critical functions. There is more check on them to prevent the user of waiting in front of an infinite loading. But I found my code very repetitive, not very pretty and not really useful to use. Here is a test on one function:

```js
var NWindow = {
    network_bg: null,
    network_title: null,
    network_close: null,
    init: function() {

        // Check if the window exist in the DOM.
        if (!this.insert()) {

            alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
            console.error(Errors.console.function_failed, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_bg");
            return false;
        }

        // Get IDs.
        this.getIds(0);

        // Check if values has been found
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty("network_bg") || !Errors.check.isjQuery(this.network_bg)) {

            alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
            console.error(Errors.null_value, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_bg");
            return false;
        }

        if (!this.hasOwnProperty("network_title") || !Errors.check.isjQuery(this.network_bg)) {

            console.warn(Errors.console.null_value, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_title");
        }

        if (!this.hasOwnProperty("network_close") || !Errors.check.isjQuery(this.network_close)) {

            alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
            console.error(Errors.console.null_value, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_close");
            return false;
        }

        // Vérifie que les éléments HTML nécessaires existent.
        if (!Errors.check.elementExist(this.network_bg)) {

            alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
            console.error(Errors.console.missing_html, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_bg");
            return false;
        }

        if (!Errors.check.elementExist(this.network_title)) {

            console.warn(Errors.console.missing_html, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_title");
        }

        if (!Errors.check.elementExist(this.network_close)) {

            alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
            console.error(Errors.console.missing_html, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_close");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    },
    [...]
}

var Errors = {
    check: {
        isjQuery: function(obj) {
            return (obj && (obj instanceof jQuery || obj.constructor.prototype.jquery));
        },
        elementExist: function($query) {
            return ($query && ($query.length > 0));
        }
    },
    alert: {
        window_error: "Erreur: Impossible d'ouvrir la fenêtre. Consultez la console pour plus d'informations."
    },
    console: {
        function_failed: "[%s] La fonction {%s} a renvoyée une erreur.",
        null_value: "[%s] La valeur de {%s} est nulle.",
        missing_html: "[%s] L'élément HTML {%s} n'existe pas."
    }
}
```

As we can see, there are fifty lines just for two functions in init. Do you have any idea how I could improve the code? Some values just use "console.warn", others use "console.error" and "alert". I have thought about put every check in a function, but it still be ugly.

Thank you in advance

Comment: probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: None of the `this.hasOwnProperty` checks are necessary. You defined the properties in the same object literal. You also don’t need the `isjQuery` check because you check for `elementExist` later. In general: bad: defensive programming against contrived problems; good: automated tests, types.

Comment: You could put your `if's` into functions and close it inside function checkErrors for example...

Comment: @Ry- Some test before showed me that a defined property to null is not shown in the console (with console.log) and using it without hasOwnProperties can throw an error.

And what if I do a `.lenght` if it's not a JQuery object ? It could work with a string or an array, but not every time. Unless I'm forget something ?

Comment: Why would it be a string or array instead of a jQuery object? It’s your code. Also, there was something wrong with your tests, because properties initialized to null in an object literal are always own properties unless you delete them. Accessing a normal property that doesn’t exist never causes an error either.

Comment: Yeah, it's my code. But I leave the company in two months, so I have to make it clear and add error handling for people who work on this after.

Comment: This redundant error handling is not helping make anything clear. (When I say “your code” I don’t mean literally yours, but that there’s nobody you’re defending against. Your fellow developers will not intentionally sabotage your property types, and you cannot stop them from making mistakes. Catching mistakes early is good, yes, but not like this. Again: automated tests, types.)

Comment: I **need** to do it so why ask ?

Comment: No, you don’t need to do it. You just think you do. Common problem. Anyway, I think I’ve covered the essentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function:

```
        // Check if values has been found
    if (!this.hasOwnProperty("network_bg") || !Errors.check.isjQuery(this.network_bg)) {

        alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
        console.error(Errors.null_value, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_bg");
        return false;
    }

    if (!this.hasOwnProperty("network_title") || !Errors.check.isjQuery(this.network_bg)) {

        console.warn(Errors.console.null_value, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_title");
    }

    if (!this.hasOwnProperty("network_close") || !Errors.check.isjQuery(this.network_close)) {

        alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
        console.error(Errors.console.null_value, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_close");
        return false;
    }

    // Vérifie que les éléments HTML nécessaires existent.
    if (!Errors.check.elementExist(this.network_bg)) {

        alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
        console.error(Errors.console.missing_html, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_bg");
        return false;
    }

    if (!Errors.check.elementExist(this.network_title)) {

        console.warn(Errors.console.missing_html, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_title");
    }

    if (!Errors.check.elementExist(this.network_close)) {

        alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
        console.error(Errors.console.missing_html, "NWindow.init", "Nwindow.network_close");
        return false;
    }
```

You can replace with this:

```
        const networks = ["network_bg", "network_close"]
    const warnNetworks = ["network_title"]
    networks.forEach(element => {
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty(element) || !Errors.check.isjQuery(this.network_bg)) {
            alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
            console.error(Errors.null_value, "NWindow.init", `Nwindow.${element}`);
            return false;
        }
        if (!Errors.check.elementExist(this[element])) {
            alert(Errors.alert.window_error);
            console.error(Errors.console.missing_html, "NWindow.init", `Nwindow${element}`);
            return false;
        }
    })
    warnNetworks.forEach(element => {
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty(element) || !Errors.check.isjQuery(this.network_bg)) {
            console.warn(Errors.console.null_value, "NWindow.init", `Nwindow.${element}`);
        }
        if (!Errors.check.elementExist(this[element])) {
            console.warn(Errors.console.missing_html, "NWindow.init", `Nwindow.${element}`);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Yeah that a solution. I did'nt think about it. I will wait a little longer but I will maybe used this. Thanks